# 1, 2, 3: Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

## Ask 1:

No reason to keep me, I’m profitless math

## Shift 1:

You ask me, I’ll teach you to follow a path

## Keep 2:

Do rotate your head, and you might spot a tent

## Add 2:

You will hear a word that reorders events

## Grow 3:

The same to the ear, if not so to the eye

## Take 3:

To say I exist is the same as to lie!

...

Who am I?

Hint:

> How many letters does the answer have?

Hint 2:

> You shouldn't be looking for a noun.

Hint 3:

> I might have used words that confuse puzzle-solvers here and there. One could consider different interpretations for some of the words in the riddle.

Hint 4:

> You look for more hints? Half the hints are a dead giveaway!

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> a bunch of keyboard keys :P I couldn't find out the algorithm of "ask1-shift1-keep2-add2-grow3-take3" yet.

No reason to keep me, I’m profitless math

> shift key

You ask me, I’ll teach you to follow a path

> [? /] key. "?" represents the "ask" and "/" represents the path.

Do rotate your head, and you might spot a tent

> [<] [>] keys right next to it

You will hear a word that reorders events

> backspace(?!not really sure)

The same to the ear, if not so to the eye

> caps lock, changes the way letters look, not the sounds

To say I exist is the same as to lie!

> spacebar

Comment: this seems sound, except you have not explained "ask" "shift" "add" etc.

Comment: Some of these look really good! However, my first impression that add/shift/keep meant to shift/keep/etc the letters in the previous word to obtain the new one. Ask could be because it's the first word. But grow doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I am not a bunch of keyboard keys. :) Interesting answer, though (+1). Can you explain why you thought "No reason to keep me, I’m profitless math" matches with the shift key? Everything else seems to work (except for the numbers, which are an important part of the puzzle).

Answer (score 1):

Ask 1: No reason to keep me, I’m profitless math

> GPS calculation is not financially profitable

Shift 1: You ask me, I’ll teach you to follow a path

> You can use GPS to navigate

Keep 2: Do rotate your head, and you might spot a tent

> Maybe referring to the pointer arrow on GPS devices that mark your position and direction

Add 2: You will hear a word that reorders events

> The word "TURN" can reorder events (can be referring to events that have taken place, such as turns made and recalculation of route, or recalculation of a different route due to unexpected direction change by GPS subject)

Grow 3: The same to the ear, if not so to the eye

> If two people are in the proximity of the same GPS system, they will hear and see the same thing, or atleast hear the same thing if one or both are not looking at the screen

Take 3: To say I exist is the same as to lie!

> The GPS pointer arrow that marks your position is only virtually there on a GPS system, and cannot be physically spotted at your current position although it displays on the screen.

The Answer is

> GPS

Comment: This is not the actual answer, but GPS is the key to one of the hints (and you explained that hint perfectly)! I will not say which hint I'm talking about, that would be too easy. :) Also, you will have to use the numbers to get the answer. They're there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got enough here to post a partial answer. Maybe it will inspire someone else, just as coderodour's answer inspired this one.

No reason to keep me, I'm profitless math

> `vain gator` because vain == profitless and, math is stretched to gator because the greater and less than signs can be colloquially referred to as 'gators'. Unless it's 'gate', which lends itself more readily to math.

You ask me, I'll teach you to follow a path

> `navigator` (or `navigate`) because 'vain' is shifted to 'navi', and navigation is following a path.

Do rotate you head, and you might spot a tent

> `or` because in logic, 'or' is represented by a 'v', which rotated looks like a tent when rotated 180 degrees.

You will hear a word that reorders events

> `bfor` because it sounds like 'before', which is a chronologically operative word. It's also 4 letters, keeping to the steps 'keep 2' and then 'add 2'

The same to the ear, if not so to the eye

> Not sure, but I believe it's 7 letters because of "grow 3."

To say I exist is the same as to lie.

> Again, not sure, but I think it's 4 letters ("take 3")

Comment: You got the hints "Do rotate [...] tent" and "You will hear [...] events" right!

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Santa

I can't really explain why, but I believe that you are.

I also believe Shift 1 is:

> Satnav

Apart from that, and the obvious 'to say I exist is the same as to lie', i've got nothing.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. But you're thinking around the right lines for "Shift 1"!

Answer (score -1):

Ask 1:
No reason to keep me, I’m profitless math

> ESC escape key in the keyboard

Shift 1:
You ask me, I’ll teach you to follow a path

> F1 is for Help

Keep 2:
Do rotate your head, and you might spot a tent

> F3 is for search it will open a box to write inside

Add 2:
You will hear a word that reorders events

> F5 To refresh the computer and reorder information

Grow 3:
The same to the ear, if not so to the eye

> Caps Lock you go to the Home Row, it will grow the letters   (Upper case)

Take 3:
To say I exist is the same as to lie!

> You return to Escape it will remove the last action

The Answer is

> ESC the escape key in the keyboard